# Why pipelining in firefox does not seem to work?

Tags: http, pipelining, http-pipelining

To verify that using http pipelining can optimize the speed of loading resources, I made a test as follows:

Open Firefox on Mac, in config change max connection per server to 1, then I open a test page which loads 12 images. I got the following figure:

[image]

The browser load each image one by one and 12 images cost about 12 seconds to load(i add 1 sec delay for each image).

Next, I turn on pipelining in Firefox, and refresh the page. I got the following figure:

[image]

I can see there is no blocking at all. All requests are pipelined. I suppose the total time of loading will be shortened but unfortunately it's the same with that of no pipelining. So I doubt the pipelining doesn't seem to work.

I want to know why and how can I fix it. I use apache server. Are there any configs need to be made in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

As [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) said,

> The pipelining of requests results in a dramatic improvement in the loading times of HTML pages, **especially over high latency connections** such as satellite Internet connections. The speedup is **less apparent** on **broadband connections**

Your test is based on a typical broadband connection. It is so short (a moment can be ignored) for the server to receive each request and every time it sends such a big picture, whole bandwidth of the connection is occupied.

So, you can retry your test with:

1. High latency on each request.
2. Many tiny files as resources to response.